# Exchange Server SMTP Auth Login gets rejected

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp-auth

I have an Exchange 2010 Server that denies SMTP logins on a seperate receive connector for no clear reason.
For a groupware I have to enable "auth login" on the receive connector. "Basic Authentication" and the "Exchange Users" groups are enabled on the receive connector.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ReceiveConnector -Identity "*MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED"  | fl


RunspaceId                              : b578795d-0460-41eb-87b8-e7b223867968
AuthMechanism                           : BasicAuth
Banner                                  :
BinaryMimeEnabled                       : True
Bindings                                : {*IP-ADDRESS REMOVED*:25}
ChunkingEnabled                         : True
DefaultDomain                           :
DeliveryStatusNotificationEnabled       : True
EightBitMimeEnabled                     : True
BareLinefeedRejectionEnabled            : False
DomainSecureEnabled                     : False
EnhancedStatusCodesEnabled              : True
LongAddressesEnabled                    : False
OrarEnabled                             : False
SuppressXAnonymousTls                   : False
AdvertiseClientSettings                 : False
Fqdn                                    : *FQDN REMOVED*
Comment                                 :
Enabled                                 : True
ConnectionTimeout                       : 00:10:00
ConnectionInactivityTimeout             : 00:05:00
MessageRateLimit                        : unlimited
MessageRateSource                       : IPAddress
MaxInboundConnection                    : 5000
MaxInboundConnectionPerSource           : 20
MaxInboundConnectionPercentagePerSource : 2
MaxHeaderSize                           : 64 KB (65,536 bytes)
MaxHopCount                             : 60
MaxLocalHopCount                        : 12
MaxLogonFailures                        : 3
MaxMessageSize                          : 10 MB (10,485,760 bytes)
MaxProtocolErrors                       : 5
MaxRecipientsPerMessage                 : 200
PermissionGroups                        : ExchangeUsers, Custom
PipeliningEnabled                       : True
ProtocolLoggingLevel                    : Verbose
RemoteIPRanges                          : {*IP-ADDRESS REMOVED*}
RequireEHLODomain                       : False
RequireTLS                              : False
EnableAuthGSSAPI                        : False
ExtendedProtectionPolicy                : None
LiveCredentialEnabled                   : False
TlsDomainCapabilities                   : {}
Server                                  : *HOSTNAME REMOVED*
SizeEnabled                             : Enabled
TarpitInterval                          : 00:00:05
MaxAcknowledgementDelay                 : 00:00:30
AdminDisplayName                        :
ExchangeVersion                         : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Name                                    : *MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED*
DistinguishedName                       : CN=*MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED*,CN=SMTP Receive Connectors,CN=Protocols,CN=*HOSTNAME REMOVED,CN=Serv
                                          ers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Grou
                                          ps,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,D
                                          C=*DOMAIN NAME REMOVED*,DC=local
Identity                                : *HOSTNAME REMOVED*\*MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED*
Guid                                    : ea8993a2-85df-45fb-81ec-ccc09630f2a2
ObjectCategory                          : *DOMAIN NAME REMOVED*.local/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Smtp-Receive-Connector
ObjectClass                             : {top, msExchSmtpReceiveConnector}
WhenChanged                             : 30.10.2018 15:16:45
WhenCreated                             : 30.10.2018 14:07:02
WhenChangedUTC                          : 30.10.2018 14:16:45
WhenCreatedUTC                          : 30.10.2018 13:07:02
OrganizationId                          :
OriginatingServer                       : *FQDN REMOVED*
IsValid                                 : True
```

A sample from the stmp-receive log reads as followed:

```
220 *FQDN REMOVED* Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 30 Oct 2018 14:37:03 +0100",
ehlo test,
250-*FQDN REMOVED* Hello [*IP-ADDRESS REMOVED*],
250-SIZE 10485760,
250-PIPELINING,
250-DSN,
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,
250-AUTH LOGIN,
250-8BITMIME,
250-BINARYMIME,
250 CHUNKING,
auth login,
334 <authentication response>,
334 <authentication response>,
Inbound AUTH LOGIN failed because of LogonDenied
User Name: *USERNAME REMOVED*
Tarpit for '0.00:00:05',
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful,
```

I tried so far:

- Using "anonymous authentication", after enabling it, the groupware can send mails. It is not an option to leave anonymous enabled though (I'd have to add all clients IP Adresses to the receive connector, because it seems that the groupware client itself tries to logon to the Exchange server.)
- Telnet sessions to the Exchange server look a lot like the groupware login trace I provided, after issuing "auth login" and the credentials in base64 I just receive "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful" from the server
- Tried different styles of the username: domain\username, username@domain, username only, all the same result.
- Added explizit permissions for username to the receive connector (`Get-ReceiveConnector -Identity "*MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED*" | Add-ADPermission -User "*USERNAME REMOVED*" -ExtendedRights ms-Exch-SMTP-Submit`) and checked if they are in place
- Checked if any ADPermission is in place that would deny a logon of that user (`Get-ReceiveConnector -Identity "*MAILRELAY NAME REMOVED" | Get-ADPermission | ft ExtendedRights,User,Deny`), it is not.
- Switched to another user for testing (domain user, domain admin), all the same

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Since the groupware logs seem to be somehow inaccurate or badly formated, here is my telnet session for further reference.

```
220 *FQDN REMOVED* Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 31 Oct 2018 11:14:57 +0100
ehlo test
250-*FQDN REMOVED* Hello [*IP REMOVED*]
250-SIZE 10485760
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
*BASE64 ENCODED USERNAME* (user@domain.com)
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
*BASE64 ENCODED PASSWORD*
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

Comment: I already have a workaround for this problem involving the on-site firewall and using another smarthost for the delivery of the groupware mails. Nevertheless I cannot find any error in my configuration above, so the question remains open.

Comment: I notice a couple of things wrong in the log. Every line ends with a `,` which isn't supposed to be there. The `334` response code is seen twice suggesting the server somehow thought it received two commands even though only one appear in the log.

Comment: Thanks, I added a transcript of the telnet session for further reference - maybe the logging format of the groupware is not accurate or misleading.